# Gzip-compressed SVG images on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, svg, gzip

I'm fairly new to rails and I'm in the final stages of testing my first rails site on Heroku. I run PageSpeed Insights and it seems that even after enabling the 'heroku-deflater' gem, the compressed versions of the css and js files are loading fine but the gz svg files seem to be ignored (I double checked and they exist on Amazon S3, where the asset files are being hosted).

Any ideas how to tell Heroku to look for the gzip-compressed SVG files instead of the full ones?